# model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Error: model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

I want to do abstract api for all models in my app

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/object/', views.GeneralViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
]
```

views.py

```
class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @property
    def model(self, request):
        return apps.get_model(app_label=self.request.data.get('app'),
                              model_name=self.request.data.get('object'))

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return self.model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self, request):
        GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = self.model
        return GeneralSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I expect the list of my data of models

for example  for post api  of

```
{
    "app": "leads",
    "object": "Lead"
}
```

expect all data from Lead object

Comment: You can not make `model` a `@property` if it requires a `request`.

Comment: You was right. thank you very much